# Do I need higher transaction isolation to make constraints work reliably in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, transactions, unique-constraint, postgresql-9.5, isolation-level

I have a case where I need to check if a row exists, and if it exists to not creating it again. Pretty much summed like this below:

```
select id from table where constraintA=$1 and constraintB=$2
```

following right after that in my code:

```
if not exist
insert into table values ($1,$2, {other data})
```

To ensure that constraint are correct, I can make an unique index like `unique(constraintA,constraintB)`.

But, in https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/transaction-iso.html it says that Postgres uses locks on rows, and newly created data is isolated from other concurrent transactions. So they wont block each other, as I am not updating or deleting data.

Which brings me to my question, do I need an isolation level higher than `read committed` to ensure the correctness? if not, is my understanding correct?

PS: I am using Postgres 10.5

Comment: The unique constraint will take care of that.

Comment: Thanks for fast reply. But to my understanding, they supposedly cannot see the new created data from other transactions, how can the unique constraint come into play here?

Comment: Because this happens in the internal code of Postgres which does have access to that information

Comment: Also you should do [`insert ... on conflict do nothing`](https://www.depesz.com/2015/05/10/waiting-for-9-5-add-support-for-insert-on-conflict-do-nothingupdate/) to avoid errors.

Comment: @Tometzky Thanks for the info. Fortunately, for my specific case it would be better to throw error instead, so my apps can notify the user

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right to worry, but you can rely on database constraints to work as you expect, even in the face of concurrent transactions.

Constraints are implemented as special triggers in PostgreSQL, and the trigger functions involved “break” MVCC by taking a new snapshot that will also see uncommitted rows.

This is not in the regular documentation; for topics like this, the documentation is in the source. See [`src/backend/utils/adt/ri_triggers.c`](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=src/backend/utils/adt/ri_triggers.c), particularly [this part](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=src/backend/utils/adt/ri_triggers.c;h=b4d0029877b5d3b8693b758353f2400cf6a8d121;hb=HEAD#l1449) of `RI_Initial_Check`.

Comment: Any link regarding this? I want to read more, but can't find it on postgres docs

Comment: For this level of depth, you have to go to the (open) source. Do you want pointers to the source?

Comment: That would be great

Comment: I have added links to the answer.